# Add a virtual driver using C#

Tags: c#, virtual, driver, printing

How to add a virtual driver that contains functions that calls C# functions inside a DLL file.

Comment: Drivers exist in kernel space and cannot call functions in user space - even simple C functions.

Comment: Is there a way to put the C# functions in a place to expose them to be called from a kernel space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Perhaps if you told us what you are trying to do, we could help you with a more realistic solution.

Comment: I want to add a virtual printer driver that will call a C# function that makes for example an upload of documents to sharepoint.

Comment: I want the virtual driver as a third party to call C# DLL that contains a function to upload a document to sharepoint

Comment: I want to know if I can make it like snagit virtual printer with C#

Comment: i was thinking of doing something like that, let me try to understand it, You want to add a printer so people can print to it but instead of printing into a paper you want to do something with the document? (achieve maybe?)

Comment: Yes , i want to upload documents and files if possible.

Comment: If you know : Snagit : http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/snagit-9-screen-capture-review-download-free-license/3520/

I need to make something alike that uploads documents to sharepoint or anything else , but calling C# functions.